# Get actual touch position LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When using `Gdx.input.getX()` or `Gdx.input.getY()` the position seems to be fine on the computer but when I put it on an Android tablet the position is completely off.

I've done some research and saw somewhere that it was mentioned I should use `camera.unproject(Vector3)` but I'm not sure if that's what I need to use or how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Pause extends Screen
{
Vector3 touchPoint;
Pause()
{
 touchPoint = new Vector3();
}
void update(float deltaTime)
{       
if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if(OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(Assets.resumeButton.getBoundingRectangle(), touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y))
        {
            some thing u want to do
        }

}
```

Comment: hope u r familiar with OverlapTester class

Comment: Never heard of it.. lol I could probably figure it out thanks

Comment: public class OverlapTester {

 public static boolean overlapRectangles(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {
  if (r1.x < r2.x + r2.width && r1.x + r1.width > r2.x
    && r1.y < r2.y + r2.height && r1.y + r1.height > r2.y)
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }

 public static boolean pointInRectangle(Rectangle r, Vector2 p) {
  return r.x <= p.x && r.x + r.width >= p.x && r.y <= p.y
    && r.y + r.height >= p.y;
 }

 public static boolean pointInRectangle(Rectangle r, float x, float y) {
  return r.x <= x && r.x + r.width >= x && r.y <= y
    && r.y + r.height >= y;
 }
}

Comment: Rectangle is of what type ? Have to import from Libgdx or java.awt ?

Comment: From libgdx. Awt wont run on android device

Comment: getBoundingRectangle is not there , what is the alternate.

Comment: Its there in sprite and atlassprite

Comment: On which class object you are searching getboundingrectangle

Comment: Yeah i got the method.How to do it for circular image and i want to get bounding box of that circle and also check points in circle or no?